# WPF C# get grid height after setting to auto

Tags: c#, wpf

So, i tried making a `Grid`

```cs
public GridDisplay(String title, int rows, int columns) 
{
    MyGrid = new Grid();
    this.rows = rows;
    this.columns = columns;


    MyGrid.Margin = new Thickness(12, 12, 12, 12);

    for (int x = 0; x < columns; x++) 
    {
        ColumnDefinition c = new ColumnDefinition();
        c.Width = GridLength.Auto;
        MyGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(c);
    }
    
    for (int y = 0; y < rows; y++) 
    {
        RowDefinition r = new RowDefinition();
        r.Height = GridLength.Auto;
        MyGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(r);
    }
}
```

After setting the `Width` of each `Column` and the `Height` of each `Row` to `auto`, I want to retrieve the values of those height/width after the construction of the `Grid`.
How do I do that?
I've tried these:

```cs
g.RenderSize.Width;
g.RenderSize.Height;
g.ColumnDefinitions[0].Width
g.ColumnDefinitions[0].ActualWidth
g.ColumnDefinitions[0].MinWidth
```

None of these gave the correct rendered value of the grid.

Comment: Where do you try to get the actual height and width? In the constructor?

Comment: `grid.ActualWidth` should hold the correct value.

Comment: I'm making a ```Grid``` object with that constructor, have a method that returns the object so I can get the size of it.
Btw, @MichałTurczyn , that returns 0 to me, why I have a 5x5 Grid.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the `Grid` height or width isn't calculated until the `InitializeComponent();` render the actual object and calculates the auto value.